# Number of sets with given size that cover the set of pairs.

Tags: combinatorics

Assume we have $L$ distinct numbers.

I want to calculate the minimum number of sets of size $a$ that are needed so that all unordered pairs of numbers are contained in at least one of the sets.

I understand that finding the sets is similar to the set cover problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem (right?),
but is there an easier/faster way to calculate the minimum number without calculating the sets, given $L$ and $a$?

Comment: Are the numbers in $L$ all distinct, i.e. it suffices to consider $L=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ for some $n=|L|$?

Comment: Yes, they are distinct

Comment: Easy bounds are $\frac{L(L-1)}{a(a-1)}\le N(L,a)\le\frac{L(L-1)}{a-1}$

Comment: An alternative characterization is "what is the smallest number of $K_a$ subgraphs needed to [edge cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_cover) the complete graph $K_L$?"